Given a natutal number N, find the maximum possible product of a set of numbers whose sum is N
Given a natutal number N, find the maximum possible product of a set of positive integers whose sum is N. I read the solution and they split the problems in 3 cases by the reminder of N. If N is divisible by 3, then we write N as a sum of 3's and the other 2 cases are similar, they just add a 2 or two to reduce N in the first case. I don't know how to prove this is correct. Can anybody help me?

You can use induction.  A key point is that for $N=6 = 3+3=2+2+2=4+2$ you have $3^2>2^3=4\times 2$.

You need to add some quantifiers. What set of numbers? Integers? Reals? Also I suppose you mean positive.

They are positive integers. And a question for Henry, how to show in my induction step that using 3's is better than all the options to write the sum?

This is another "easier" solution of the original question
If the numbers of that set are positive real numbers you can try it by using AM $\geq$ GM.
Let $\{x_i:i=1,...,n\}$ be a set of $n$ positive real numbers such that $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=N$, then, by the $AM\geq GM$ inequality we have $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{n}\geq(\prod_{i=1}^n x_i)^{\frac{1}{n}}$. This means that $\prod_{i=1}^n x_i\leq\left(\frac{N}{n}\right)^n.$ I think you can estimate a better solution, but this is a good start.
